# print format in apache commons logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-commons

Using log4j underneath.

How can I do,  format or wildcard stuff like:

```
System.out.printf('%s', 5)
```

With

`log.info('%s', 5)  //org.apache.commons.logging.Log instance`

Version:commons-logging-1.1.3.jar.

The bad thingy about this mentioned API is:

It has methods `info(object)`  and `info(object, throwable)` only.

Or logging did not evolve there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is included in log4j2:

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/2.1/apache-log4j-2.1-bin.zip

You have to include at least two jar files:

- log4j-api-2.1.jar
- log4j-core-2.1.jar

Finally put a configuration file named "log4j2.xml" in your classpath which can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

After the configuration you should be able to achieve what you want with the following code:

```
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(YOURCLASSNAME.class);
log.printf(Level.INFO,"%s",5);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the easiest way to do it

```
log.info(String.format("%s", 5));
```

Comment: Since log4j version 1.2.16 you can use the LogMF or LogSF class, but before that log4j doesn't have the capability built in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is achievable in "slf4j". Try using the below snapshots-

log.info("My name is %s  %s",firstName,secondName)

or

LOG.debug("WidgetName:{}\n curWidgetVOArray=\n",curWidgetName, curWidgetVOArray);

Refer - http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/08/why-use-sl4j-over-log4j-for-logging-in.html